# Where are the kubernetes containers running?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I have a one node cluster (managed by Rancher) which wasn't setup by me so I dont know the details.

`kubectl get nodes` returns one node named `node-1`; 
`kubectl get pods -o wide` shows that every (~40) pod running on that `node-1` (of course).

But when I ssh into `node-1` as root the `docker ps` command shows only `rancher/rancher:v2.6.3` as running container.

So what hides Rancher from us? Where can I access the docker context of the running pods?

Comment: Is that self-hosted Kubernetes cluster or EKS or AKS...?

Comment: @RichardRublev   selfhosted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docker ps` command most likely won't return what you expected because Kubernetes dropped Docker as a container runtime about a year ago. This doesn't mean container images built by Docker won't run in Kubernetes, it just means that some of Docker's underlying functionalities are not included with Kubernetes.

It seems that Rancher itself does run as a Docker container, however the pods themselves do not. If you wanted to interact with the pods from within the node, you can look into [nerdctl](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl) or [ctr](https://github.com/projectatomic/containerd/blob/master/docs/cli.md) (assuming your cluster's container runtime is [containerd](https://github.com/containerd/containerd)).